# OpenCV VideoWriter Internal Data Flow Error

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote a simple C++ programm to read a video from file, apply some filters and save the video to another file using VideoWriter.
The programm compiles without errors or warnings.
When I run the programm however, I get the following error message:

> GStreamer Plugin: Embedded video playback halted; module appsrc0
>   reported: Internal data flow error.

Here is the code that creates the error:

```
VideoWriter oVideoWriter;
oVideoWriter.open(file_out,CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'),framerate_out,out_size,true);
/*
...
*/    
oVideoWriter.write(Mat_out);
```

The same thing happens if I just try to write the unmodified video stream, so the algorythm inbetween should not be the problem.